# Fast method to copy variables to all rows in dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe 500,000+ rows which only contains the ID on the "BASE" row, all subsequent "row" row contains information about the ID.

I want to copy the ID into each of the rows so there is an easy way to determine what ID the information belongs too.

As this is a large dataframe simply iterating through the rows using the below code is incredibly time-consuming, I ran it for an hour and it only made it 1/5th through the dataframe. I will be running this frequently thus need a faster method.

Ultimately I want to be able to use vectorization in numpy to give the fastest results that I know of using numpy.where(). I have tried updating global variables within functions when an "IDinRow' variable = TRUE, however, it simply creates a series for that global variable. I want the global variable to update each time the function is called to within np.where. However, I do not know how to do this. Or any quick method

This is what I want to achieve

```
    0   1   2   IDInRow ID_Numpy
0   BASE    1234567 nan True    1234567
1   row 1   USD False   1234567
2   row 1   USD False   1234567
3   row Amount  USD False   1234567
4   row 1   USD False   1234567
5   row 1   USD False   1234567
6   row 1   USD False   1234567
7   BASE    7654321 nan True    7654321
8   row 1   EUR False   7654321
9   row 1   EUR False   7654321
10  row Amount  EUR False   7654321
11  row 1   EUR False   7654321
```

With Code below this is what I amn achieving, I want ID_Numpy to equal ID_Iterrow

```
    0   1   2   IDInRow ID  ID_Iterrow  ID_Numpy
0   BASE    1234567 nan True    1234567 1234567 1234567
1   row 1   USD False   1   1234567 1
2   row 1   USD False   1   1234567 1
3   row Amount  USD False   1   1234567 1
4   row 1   USD False   1   1234567 1
5   row 1   USD False   1   1234567 1
6   row 1   USD False   1   1234567 1
7   BASE    7654321 nan True    7654321 7654321 7654321
8   row 1   EUR False   1   7654321 1
9   row 1   EUR False   1   7654321 1
10  row Amount  EUR False   1   7654321 1
11  row 1   EUR False   1   7654321 1
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def IDLocator(ID):
        global strGlobalID
        strGlobalID = ID
        return strGlobalID

strSearch = 'BASE'

Data = {0:['BASE','row','row','row','row','row','row','BASE','row','row','row','row'],
        1:[1234567,1,1,'Amount',1,1,1,7654321,1,1,'Amount',1],
        2:['nan','USD','USD','USD','USD','USD','USD','nan','EUR','EUR','EUR','EUR']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Data)

#Creates Logic Around Delimiter In ID
df['IDInRow'] =  df[0].str.contains(strSearch)

#Adds the ID into the ID column
df['ID'] = np.where(df['IDInRow'] == True, df[1], 1)

#What I am trying to make work by using global variables and np.where
df['ID_Numpy'] = np.where(df['IDInRow'] == True, IDLocator(df['ID']), strGlobalID)

#Works But Very Slow
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df['ID'][index] != 1:
        strDealID = df['ID'][index] 
        df['ID'][index]  = strDealID
    else:
        df['ID'][index]  = strDealID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['newID'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[1] if row[0] == 'BASE' else np.nan, axis=1)
df['newID'] = df['newID'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
```